# How to get the total number of videos in a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube-analytics

I want to get the count of the total no of video uploaded to a YouTube channel using YouTube analytics API. Can any one please tell me the correct metric and dimension combination for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the videos count by using the following request.....

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/YourChannelID/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0
```

Comment: This is no longer supported

Comment: No longer available.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following URL for the Data API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=VideoLecturesChannel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Look for `statistics.videoCount` in the response. The docs for the endpoint [are here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list).

Comment: If you want this for just one or more channels and dont't want to make a whole new script for it, the google developers link given in this answer has its own tool on that page itself : just put in the channel or user id and click the blue button. You'll get the response and can copy it over.